# Getting create cypher in Neo4j for existing nodes

Tags: neo4j

In the MySQL database, I can get the create table statements like this of an existing table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Table_Name;
```

Is there any way in Neo4J to get an existing graph?I have these graphs in my database and I want to back up its query somehow if possible for later use. As I don't need a graph from this at the moment and writing a new cipher later would be time taking. For the sake of cleaning up the database, I want to get the CREATE cipher for the database. Is there any possibility of that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the whole database to a Cypher Script, using `APOC` functions, something like this:

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.all("all-plain.cypher", {
    format: "plain",
    useOptimizations: {type: "UNWIND_BATCH", unwindBatchSize: 20}
})
YIELD file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize
RETURN file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize;
```

You can read about all the options present [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/cypher/#export-cypher-neo4j-browser).

Comment: I had to install APOC functions to get it working

Comment: Yeah, that's the only way, right now.